# Emulador android

Tags: android, emulador

Quando rodo a aplicação meu emulador não mostra os componentes para testar:

[image: Print]

Answer (score 2):

A mensagem diz:

> Running an x86 based android virtual device (AVD) is 10x faster. We
>   strongly recommended creating a new AVD.

Numa tradução direta seria:

> A execução de um dispositivo virtual Android (AVD) x86 é 10x mais
>   rápido. Recomendamos fortemente a criação de um novo AVD.

Para você realizar o que a IDE indica, você teria que criar uma nova AVD para emular sua aplicação. Entre no **Android SDK Manager** e verifique se já está instalado esse pacote junto com sua API e no Extras. Veja um exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Caso não esteja instalado o pacote, instale-o e crie uma nova AVD com as especificações indicadas.

Como estas a usar Windows, veja abaixo um exemplo de AVD com CPU/ABI *Intel Atom(x86)*:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: o problema e que quando eu rodo dou um ok e sai essa msn porem os buttons e o textviwer não aparecem para poder testar

Comment: @HelenaFaria talvez seja porque a maquina virtual está muito pesada pra rodar seu app. Não está aparecendo nada porque a AVD não iniciou nem o Android provavelmente. Tente criar uma outra AVD com as indicações da IDE. Talvez fique, como eles dizem, 10 vezes mais rápido, a ponto de pelo menos Abrir o ANDROID.

Comment: como crio essa adv todas as que criei ficam da mesma maneira

Comment: Existe a possibilidade de ser o driver da placa de video